# Is there an R function similar to TDIST(x, degrees of freedom, tails) in Excel?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I am doing some homework and have been restricted to using R. I need a function that works exactly the same as `TDIST(x,df,tail)` that is available in `Excel`. The values I have found are `t = 1.92` and `df = 5` and it is 2-tailed.

I have tried using `dt(x, df, ncp, log = false)` but I cannot make that work to get the correct answer.

So, if there is a function in R that will give me the same answer as `=TDIST(1.92, 5, 2)`, that would be perfect.

The result of the function should be 0.116

Comment: When I run `=TDIST(1.92, 9, 2)` in excel I get `0.087` not `0.116`
`

Comment: @G5W Sorry, I meant 5 for the degrees of freedom. I have corrected the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I think you got the Excel result wrong. When I run

```
=TDIST(1.92, 9, 2)
```

I get 0.087056

And basically with the two-sided option what you are calculating is the probability what your t-statistic is less than -1.92 or greater than 1.92. Since the t-distribution in this case is centered, we can get the value by taking the value probability less than -1.92 and doubling it. In R, we can get the `P(x<T)` where `T~t(df)` with `pt(x, df)` So we can do

```
2*pt(-1.92, 9)
# [1] 0.0870565
```

We could define a corresponding function

```
tdist <- function(x, df) 2*pt(-abs(x), df)
tdist(1.92, 9)
# [1] 0.0870565
```

Comment: I'm sorry I gave you the wrong degrees of freedom. The degrees of freedom should be 5, not 9. Your answer works, though. Thank you much!